# how to connect to secured wireless network connection in cmd in windows?

Tags: command-line, shell, c#, prompt

I program on C#, I don't want to use P/invoke, so I will use shell,
so I need to connect to a secured wireless network connection on the CMD in windows, I know how to connect to a wireless network but I don't know where to put the password, so give me any command to connect to a secured wireless network connection

Comment: This is more suited to superuser.SE

Answer (score 0):

this might help you:
http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1597099

The Article talks about "Wireless profiles" - xml files that contain Encryption and authentication settings.

Those files can also be read from or exported from shell using Netsh.